# Substitute or replace values in the whole dataset

Tags: r, replace

My dataset is such:

```
structure(list(Data = structure(c(1672531200, 1669852800, 1667260800, 
1664582400, 1661990400, 1659312000, 1656633600, 1654041600, 1651363200, 
1648771200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    index = c(99.1, 96.2, 110.2, 105.4, 108, 80.4, 109.3, 109.9, 
    115.6, 104.7)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001f72620e040>)
```

I've downloaded it from a website:

```
url_IPI <- "https://www.idescat.cat/indicadors/?id=conj&n=10277&col=1&f=ssv"
destfile_IPI <- "G:/SUBDIRECCIO-ESTUDIS/PROJECTES/Automatitzar gràfics/Scripts R/IPI.csv"
download.file(url_IPI, destfile_IPI)

IPI <- fread("G:/SUBDIRECCIO-ESTUDIS/PROJECTES/Automatitzar gràfics/Scripts R/IPI.csv", header=TRUE, dec = ",", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

How can I substitute `..` to a blank space in the whole dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `na.strings` argument
all the `".."` within the body of the file will be replaced with `NA`.

```
IPI <- fread("IPI.csv",
             header=TRUE, dec = ",", encoding = "UTF-8",na.strings = "..")
```